# How did Muhammad (PBUH) try to convince people that he is a prophet of God?

Tags: prophet-muhammad

Three years after Muhammad (PBUH) was visited by Gabriel and received his first revelation from God, he started preaching revelations publicly, proclaiming that he is the last messenger of God, inviting people to Islam. My question is, how did he try to convince people that he is a prophet of God and people should believe in him? What reasons did he give for his claim?

Comment: Most of it was done through actions and manifest virtues; and definitely not 'forcefully'! ;) And [this Q&A](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/13324/why-take-mohammads-word) may give you some idea.

Comment: @infatuated I didn't say how "forcefully" he convinced people. I said "what reasons did he give to convince people"

Answer (score 2):

Muhammad (SAW) was known by the community as a very kind and honest person who has never wronged anyone. This was even before the visit of Angel Gabriel.

People followed Islam and started to believe that Muhammad (SAW) because the Prophet treated everyone equally and fairly which meant better and happier life (especially for the slaves). He never showed anger and was always patient even when his enemies attacked him. He always offered peace.

He told the people about the message of Allah. The words of the Qur'an touch the hearts of many. Which lead to more and more people accepting Islam.

Answer (score 0):

Just like any rassul, Muhammad (PBUH) too was gifted with miracles to convince people. However, the most important miracle is the Qur'an. At his time, there poetry competitions were very common, and when Muhammad (PBUH) brought some verses of the Qur'an, it leaved people speechless. You can read more about it [in this article](http://www.hamzatzortzis.com/essays-articles/exploring-the-Qur"an/the-inimitable-Qur'an/) by Hamza Tzortzis.

Comment: Please consider and take into account these two points: 1- Quran was not wholly available at the time Muhammad (PBUH) started his public preaching. 2- One has to be fully aware of Arabic literature to understand that Quran is different from other Arabic poems. An Arab poet might become speechless in front of Quran, but what about an ordinary man, who does not know much about Arabic literature? My question: Suppose that you are an ordinary Arab man, in the exact time when Muhammad started his public preaching. What reason convinces you that he is the last prophet of God?

Comment: @Meysam 1. It wasn't completely available but he did knew many ayat that leaved many poets of the time speechless. 2. No, even if you don't know the Arabic literature you can see that the nature of the Qu'ran is special.

Comment: 1- Does not make sense 2- How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The Quran he brought was simply a miracle for most of the people living at that time,  no one could come up with the words prophet Mohammed came up with. He also made prophesies and miracles